# Can not create new application

Tags: square-connect

I am unable to create a new application in the Square Developer portal. It just says that an error has occurred but there isn't any indication of what the error is or how to correct it.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots? Is there anything in your JavaScript console?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what to do. When setting up my developer account it seems that Square does not differentiate between a developer who wants to make their code work and a customer who wants to use their services. Once I had linked my bank account to the merchant account I was able to create the application.

But... I don't want a merchant account, I'm just developing the code.

Comment: This is not true. Square does not require you to have a bank account linked in order to create an application. I believe we've spoken on our Slack community, so feel free to reach out with more information so we can find out what may have occurred.